# Dropdownlist in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
        Category x = new Category(1, "one", 0);
        Category y = new Category(2, "two", 1);


        List<Category> cat = new List<Category>();
        cat.Add(x);
        cat.Add(y);

        ViewData["categories"] = new SelectList(cat, "id", "name");
```

My view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("categories")%>
```

But, my class Category has a property named idParent. I want the dropdown to be field with values like this: ParentName -> CategoryName

```
public class Category {int idParent, string name, int id}
```

I tried like this:

```
ViewData["categories"] = new SelectList(cat, "id", "idParent" + "name");
```

but it's not working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you open for using strongly typed views ?

Comment: Go thru my tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to the `Category` class to return the values you want.

```
public class Category 
{
    int idParent; 
    string name; 
    int id;

    public Category(int idParent, string name, int id)
    {
        this.idParent = idParent;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
     }

    public string FormattedName
    {
        get {return string.format("{0}->{1}", this.idParent, this.name);}
    }
}
```

Then your SelectList constructor becomes:

```
ViewData["categories"] = new SelectList(cat, "id", "FormattedName");
```

You may have to adjust this code to your needs but it should give you the idea.